# How to create Local Repositories in RHEL

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I need to create a local repository in RHEl 5.5. i386

Because when I type some command in terminal it say that **RHEL is not subscribed with RHN** which is true. I took it from friend.

So can someone tell me how to achieve this target.

## Further Actions based on Warl0ck instructions.

- I copied the RPM's from Mdia to /home/Umair/RPM  folder
- I installed the script createrepo-0.4.11-i386.el5.noarch.rpm located
  in Server directory of Installation Media.
  Then it took some time to generate metadata. Total Packages 2348

[image: Metadata]

- Then I create the local repo file using vi

> vi /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo

These are the entries I added.

[image: Repo text]

And finally i run this command

> yum -y install apache php{,-cgi,-cli,-gd,-mysql} mysql{,-server}

and in reply bash slapped me with error

[image: erro]

Comment: "I took it from friend.". But... why?! There are **two** perfectly good alternatives that don't cost money and are (mostly) the same thing.

Comment: U must be talking about CentOS and Fedora Am I right??? But i will also give them a try.... Thanks

Comment: One of them is CentOS. The other one is not Fedora.

Comment: Then what is other one. Isn't it the  Fedora because its the Test ground for Redhat????

Comment: Just to make it three: Scientific Linux, Oracle-Linux, CentOS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There're [plenty of document](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalRepos)s out there, given a set of RPM packages, you could do something like this,

First install the createrepo script, by

`rpm -ivh /path/to/mounted/cdrom/createrepo*.rpm` (Depends where you mounted your RedHat DVD)

Now create a folder to hold all RPMS that you want to be in the repository, e.g `RPMS`, and put the needed "*.rpm" files inside,

Then do `createrepo /path/to/RPMS` to generate metadata.

When finished, add the repository to your yum config, e.g put the following to `/etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo`

```
[local]
name=Local Repository Demo
baseurl=file:///absolute/path/to/RPMS
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
protect=1
```

Comment: dear I followed ur instructions but no use it didn't work kindly view the actions which I added in original text under the Heading ***Further Actions based on Warl0ck*** instructions.

Comment: @UmairMustafa maybe the path should be `file:///home/Umair/` in this case, I didn't try this out yet, maybe the metadata is stored in the parent folder of RPMS.

Comment: Finally i did it. But this time instead of copying rpms to /home/Umair /RPMS folder I created a folder in /media/RPMS and 2:createrepo /media/rpms and then created the local repo file and finally YUM LIST ALLand then i installed the above mentioned packages

Comment: For me the whole thing already fails in the first step because `createrepo` depends on other packages.

Comment: Your answer is for local repository, I need this repository over my local network implement by `nginx` web service. How to make repository with nginx?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to do is:

Either (not both) of:

1. Pay for a Red Hat subscription for the machine.
2. [Convert the system to CentOS.](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1502-convert-a-rhel5-linux-server-to-a-centos5-server)

Then you should find that you are able to access software and complete your task.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install create repo

   ```
   # cd /media/(dvd-label)
   # cd /Packages
   # rpm -ivh createrepo*.rpm
   ```
2. Copy all contents from dvd or just the packges

   - If whole dvd is copied, no need to run `createrepo`. Because repository is inbuilt in dvd. (To check, see if there is a repodata directory)
   - If package dir is only copied, run

     ```
     # createrepo <dir where the packages are copied>
     ```
3. Create yum repo file:

   ```
   vim dvd.repo
   [packages]
   name=packages
   baseurl=file://<dir where the packages are copied>
   enabled=1
   gpgcheck=0
   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   [packages] -- Give a name, any name
   name=packages -- description for above
   baseurl       -- location where rpms are available
   enabled=1     -- to enable this repo
   gpgcheck=0    -- not to check for GPG license file
   ```

Comment: Its been Two years since I ask for help and help is what I got, my man. I was very very noob at that time. Learned alot from community there is always a room to learn new thing.