# Installing packages after the RedHat installation?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, package-management

I was installing the RedHat 5.5 64 bit. But in hurry I forgot to install the Packages needed. And I don't want to install RH again.

How can I install packages after installation?

Comment: Do you have RHN account or not?

Comment: No my dear. 
We had a lot of conversation on this topic in this thread   http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50465/how-to-create-local-repositories-in-rhel

Comment: Wait, why do you ask here again...I think the solution is nearly the same, build a local repo or just do the `rpm -ivh XXX.rpm`

Comment: Also If you were just learning about RedHat, use CentOS instead, which is based on RedHat

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [yum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified) command to install packages.

First after installing Redhat, follows following steps to install packages.

```
$ sudo yum update
```

Then install a package using the following command:

```
$ sudo yum install <package-name>
```

**Note:** "package-name" should be exact as the name of the package present in the redhat repository.

To search the exact name of the package using a keyword, use the following yum option:

```
$ yum search <keyword>
```