# Create a repository for home-made packages for RHEL with a basic CentOS

Tags: yum, software-distribution

I work on a company network.  I have downloaded a centOS CD-ROM from the Internet but i cannot have a direct access to the Internet.

I have a limited understanding of the yum package system but I do understand that once the rpm is created then it can be put into a repository for deployment.

I would like to create rpm packages for integration into RHEL5. (Yes, people not using this system yet do exist!)

I order to understand how things should inter-operate, I would like to create a basic repository with my centOS CD-ROM (No Internet!) to automatize the deployment of my home-made softwares.

Can you help me to prove my colleagues that creating a company repository is not complicated and will automatize software distribution?

I have browse the Internet and what i found require far too dependencies for the only DVD-Rom of CentOS.  How do I manage multiple configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually asking multiple questions at once:

1. how to create a repo
2. how to resolve dependencies of a package (without internet connection)
3. what benefits does a repo bring
4. how to convince somebody a repo is actually beneficial

Some of them are already covered here, but you should refine your question what you ask for in particular and then ask separate questions if you cannot find existing answers here.

A lot of your question is already covered here:
[Creating a local yum repository without rpms](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210382/creating-a-local-yum-repository-without-rpms)

For listing the dependencies you should have a look for `repoquery` and `repotrack` which are also linked from the above question.

For creating a basic repository, have a look at `createrepo` for which several guides linked here, e.g. [How to create Local Repositories in RHEL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50465/how-to-create-local-repositories-in-rhel/)

For convincing your colleague, yes a repository can be created via two easy steps (running `createrepo` and adding a `.repo` file in `/etc/yum.repos.d`) for the other part and simply ask them what their alternative would be.
Ask them if that alternative offers dependency tracking, version comparisons, checksums for all files, permission/ownership management, pre-/post- and transition scripts handling and gpg-signing and -verification (among other features rpm offers).