# PECL - Installing PThreads offline

Tags: yum, rpm, php

I am not familiar with `pecl` command but is it possible to convert the command below to an offline version?

```
pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/pthreads-0.0.44
```

I want to install PThreads on CentOS 6.3 but the only perfect way I know is the above command. The problem is I need to install the package on machines that may or may not have internet connection. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get pthreads for PHP 5.5 or 5.6 from the [IUS project](https://ius.io).  The package names are `php55u-pecl-pthreads` and `php56u-pecl-pthreads`.  You can sync those packages to a local mirror and have them accessible without internet access.

The current version of CentOS is 6.7.  There have been several major changes between 6.3 and 6.7, so the IUS packages will probably not cleanly install on your system.  Do yourself a huge favor and get your system updated, there are tons of security issues that you are vulnerable to right now.

Comment: hey, I know it's late but I want to thank you on your answer. It helped me a lot. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

From a quick search (sadly don't have any CentOS 6.3 at hands) it seems packages for that are available via the [Remi repo](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/) and the package is named **php-pecl-pthreads**

You could try on one CentOS 6.3 box with an internet connection if this is maybe contained in the regular repositories via `yum list "*pecl-pthreads*"` - in case it is not, then you could get it from above mentioned repo.

For how to download the packages and make them available to other machines without internet connections, see answers to similar questions, e.g.

- [Creating a local yum repository without rpms](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210382/creating-a-local-yum-repository-without-rpms/211023#211023)

  or
- [Create a repository for home-made packages for RHEL with a basic CentOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226648/83329)