# Local DVD Repository with CentOS

Tags: yum, repository

I inserted the CentOS 6 dvd in my machine, mounted it with following command

```
mount /dev/cdrom /DVD
```

Then this command to create repo file

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/DVD.repo
```

And inserted these lines in that file:

```
[DVD]
name=DVD Packages
baseurl=file:///DVD
gpgcheck=0
```

Can anyone tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: a [similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50465/how-to-create-local-repositories-in-rhel?rq=1) shows an "enabled=1" setting; does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `DVD.repo` by adding `enabled=1` like this:

```
[DVD]
name=DVD Packages
baseurl=file:///DVD
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Comment: a minimal change to the OP's environment could reference their existing mountpoint of /DVD